# Invert boolean assignment in one line

Tags: python

Is there a short way to do this:

```
if flag == False:
    flag = True
```

I feel like it should be only a few letters.
I'm also curious about how other languages tackle this condition-assignment. Thank you.

**Edit**

If `flag` is `True` it needs to stay `True` therefore I can't use `flag = not flag`.
`flat = True` is indeed a one-line solution but since the statement is inside a loop I'm not sure if reassigning `flat = True` every time is good practice.

Comment: Isn't that just `flag = True`?

Comment: (Assuming, of course, that `flag` was previously either `False` or `True`. Also, comparing to `False` with `==` is pretty much always either unnecessary or wrong.)

Comment: `flag = not flag`...at least I think that's what your asking for

Comment: You're making the classic newbie mistake of putting in more work to avoid an assignment than you actually save. Assignment is cheap. Heck, you're still performing the assignment in the answer you accepted; the accepted answer is strictly more expensive than `flag = True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `if-else` do it in one line either `True` or `False

```
flag = True if 10<5 else False #(True if condition is True else False)
```

Comment: Ya but in the above code there in no loop, and it completely depends on your requirement, everytime if you need to check condition then it is necessary, or if the requirement is just to assign flag once based on condition, then place it outside of loop

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can simply invert it with a short expression:

```
flag = not flag
```

Comment: Python doesn't use `!`.

Comment: but if `flag` is `True` this code will set it to `False`.

Comment: According to the title I thought they were looking for a way to invert a boolean with one line

Answer (score 0):

For inline conditionals in general you could use

```
if flag ==  False: flag = True
```

or for just toggling a boolean you could use

```
flag = not flag
```

you could also use the ternary operator which is something like

```
flag = condition_if_true if condition else condition_if_false
```